# NativeScript Angular2 Hello World SegFault

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to get the Native Script + Angular2 template to run in the ios emulator and I keep getting a SegFault Error. I'm brand new to this platform as in I started today, so it's probably some beginner error.

Here is my error:

```
Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'F569EBB0-7559-45C5-BE3E-B07A0144F409'.
1   0x100c00c67 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:]
2   0x100833702 main
3   0x10458d92d start
undefined: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module './'. Computed path '/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F569EBB0-7559-45C5-BE3E-B07A0144F409/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1A1D0ABB-8B06-4D20-9E99-72153428ED9F/template.app/app'.
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.F569EBB0-7559-45C5-BE3E-B07A0144F409.launchd_sim[68428] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.helloworldng[0x7fa8][70509]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

To get this, I installed Angular2 and NativeScript per the instructions. It took a while, but in the end all of the tns doctor errors were resolved.

Then I got the helloworld app from NativeScript's git.     https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng.git and did `npm install`

The first time I ran it, it said it was missing tns-core-modules, so I added that to the dependencies and ran it again to get the error above.

Here is my package file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.helloworldng",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.2.1"
    }
  },
  "name": "tns-template-hello-world-ng",
  "main": "main.js",
  "version": "2.4.1",
  "author": "Telerik <support@telerik.com>",
  "description": "Nativescript Angular Hello World template",
  "license": "BSD",
  "keywords": [
    "telerik",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "nativescript",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "appbuilder",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng",
  "android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.2.1", // I Added this one
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

If I had to guess, I probably have a version issue somewhere, but I don't know enough about this platform to figure out how to fix any. Any ideas?

Let me know if you need more info. I get the same error when I try to run on android's emulator as well.

---- UPDATE -----

So I used the command  to create a blank angular nativescript app. It's also erroring but with a different error. I'm guessing that these are both symptoms of the same issue.

The Error:

```
Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'F569EBB0-7559-45C5-BE3E-B07A0144F409'.
SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: blank[71086]
SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: blank[71086]
SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: blank[71086]
SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: blank[71086]
SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: blank[71086]
assertion failed: 15A284 13E230: libxpc.dylib + 57882 [66C28065-C9DB-3C8E-926F-5A40210A6D1B]: 0x7d
Sep 11 16:08:53 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js:360:16: EXCEPTION: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js:360:16: STACKTRACE:
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js:360:16: resolvePromise@file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:425:42
    ZoneAwarePromise@file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:470:31
    then@file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:548:40
    then@file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:550:20
    then@file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:550:20
```

Then it repeats the last line a bunch of times.

Here is my packages for the blank app:

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.blank",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.2.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "^0.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: I reviewed the given error and found that this is an known issue while using Hello World NativeScript Angular2 Template. This problem has been reported in this issue -https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/444. Regarding to that as a temporary solution you could review our getting started tutorial and the project from its repo and you would be able to build the project and modify it - http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1.html. The problem doesn't affect existing project.

Comment: To build the project while using Hellow World Angular2 template you should open your `package.json` file and change `zone.js` version. Example: `"zone.js": "^0.6.12"` to `"zone.js": "0.6.17"`